# Using a SASS file in other component styles

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I am right now using Angular 2 and Webpack 1 with SASS support. It works well but when I try to use a mixin which is located in a another file but not imported in a `*.component.sass` file, it doesn't find it.

An example for my 'global' file looks like this:

```
//global.sass

@import 'animate.scss'

h1
    color: yellow

@mixin font-size($size)
    font-size: $size
```

Here is what I've already tried:

**Import global file in every `*.component.sass` file**

This is what I wanted to avoid and there two reasons for this:

- Every `@import ...` in every `*.component.sass` file results in an own `<style>...</style>`-tag even if its the same imported sass file.
- I'm to lazy to import the global file in every `*.component.sass`, because the relative path changes every time.

Is there any better solution to this?

I hope my question was acurate enough, its my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you trying to import files via a glob pattern? (e.g. `@import component.*.scss`)

Comment: Just wanted to add that I use this same technique of importing a global sass file into my component sass files. I hadn't really considered that it's possibly re-adding that global sass code to the shadow dom for every component. Have you confirmed that's what happens?